# Javascript - getting data out of array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I got this sample data.

```
"array" : [
    {"Id" : "1", "preferred" : false}, 
    {"Id" : "1", "preferred" : true }, 
    {"Id" : "2", "preferred" : false}, 
    {"Id" : "2", "preferred" : false},]
```

And i would like to get out of it something like this.

```
"array2":[{"Id": 1, numOfTrue: 1, numOfFalse: 1},{"Id": 2, numOfTrue: 0, numOfFalse: 2}]
```

What i got so far is a way how to get unique id form initial array.

```
const unique = [...new Set(array.map(item => Id))];
```

Next step would be some forEach over array and comparing Id values and setting some counters for that boolean value. So before i dive into forEach solution i would like to ask if there is another way with using .`filter()` and `.reduce()` methods.

Comment: The data you want to get out doesn't exist in the array you want to get it out of.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - I think he means that the `numOfTrue` is the number of records with that id that have a `preferred: true` value and similarly for `numOfFalse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to build a grouping object keyed to `Id`. Each time you see that `Id` again increment the value at the appropriate key. In the end your array will be the `Object.values()` of the object:

```js
let array = [
    {"Id" : "1", "preferred" : false}, 
    {"Id" : "1", "preferred" : true }, 
    {"Id" : "2", "preferred" : false}, 
    {"Id" : "2", "preferred" : false}
]

let counts = array.reduce((counts, {Id, preferred}) => {
    // If you haven't seen this Id yet, make a new entry
    if (!counts[Id]) counts[Id] = {Id, numOfTrue: 0, numOfFalse: 0}

    // increment the appropriate value:
    if (preferred) counts[Id].numOfTrue++
    else counts[Id].numOfFalse++
    return counts
}, {})

// get the values array of the object:
console.log(Object.values(counts))
```